# Background / Foreground Capability in Custom ListView Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have the following functioning code that binds `GridViewColumns` to data from a custom class:

```
<ListView Name="lv">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lvi.firstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lvi.lastName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

```
public class LVItemBox {
    public LVItem lvi { get; set; }
}
public class LVItem : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;
    public string firstName {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { SetField(ref _firstName, value); }
    }
    public string lastName {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { SetField(ref _lastName, value); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) { if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        LVItem lvi1 = new LVItem {firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe"};
        LVItem lvi2 = new LVItem {firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Smith"};
        lv.Items.Add(new LVItemBox {lvi = lvi1});
        lv.Items.Add(new LVItemBox {lvi = lvi2});
    }
}
```

My dilemma is that I want background / foreground `Brush` capability within `LVItemBox`, however if I make `LVItemBox` extend `Control`, changing `Background`/`Foreground` has no effect:

```
public class LVItemBox : Control {
    public LVItem lvi { get; set; }            // data displays
}
...
...
private void changeBackground(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LVItemBox lvib = (LVItemBox)lv.Items[0];
    lvib.Background = Brushes.Black;           // doesn't work
}
```

Furthermore, if I extend `ListViewItem` instead of `Control` I can get the background change to work, but the data bindings no longer work.

```
public class LVItemBox : ListViewItem {
    public LVItem lvi { get; set; }            // data doesn't display
}
...
...
private void changeBackground(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    LVItemBox lvib = (LVItemBox)lv.Items[0];
    lvib.Background = Brushes.Black;           // works
}
```

Any idea how I can get foreground / background capability within `LVItemBox`?

Comment: Instead of DisplayMemberBinding, you could set the CellTemplate of the GridViewColumns to a DataTemplate that contains appropriate UI elements which bind to the foreground and background properties of the item class.

Comment: When you extend `Control` I can't see any `INPC` being triggered in the setter. besides, using `Control` would break `MvvM`, also you haven't shown us how you bind that foreground or background in XAML. @Clemens is correct here, you should have used `DataTemplate`. And look into `Style`s in WPF, makes the structure a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting from `Control` works if you add the following `ItemContainerStyle` to your XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lv">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lvi.firstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lvi.lastName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @archer: Does this solve your issue? Please remember to accept the answer then.